# (Want to learn) Using Awk/SED/Echo to remove column entries on a CSV

Tags: csv, awk, sed, terminal, echo

Currently I'm running through an issue on all 50 of my spreadsheets, and I was wanting to learn how could I use Awk||sed||echo to remove column entries in my .csv files. For instance in my columns I have tons of entries that say "null" but I'd like to get that out of my sheet.
If anyone could show me how, I'd really appreciate the kindness! thanks!

My OS is OSX

Comment: [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV)

Answer (score 0):

As obliquely hinted at by choroba, this is far from trivial. However, if you are lucky, then

```
sed 's/null//g'
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it isnt working for me. I'm getting an error "illegal byte sequence" what I did was sed 's/null//g' "text name.xlsx"